# Class "app\models\category" not found in laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel-8

I am trying to get info from the database in the blade.php file(table) but the error pops-up. please tell me what I am doing wrong?
I think the problem is in the index function. tried to debug but nothing.
please tell me if you need more files to see. I'll send them quickly.
sorry if this is a beginner question. I am a beginner :(

**Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use app\models\category;

class categorycontroller extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $cat = category::all();
        return view('categories')->with('categories',$cat);
    }
```

**blade.php file**

```
@extends ('layouts.admin')




@section('content')

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<h1 class="bg-primary text-center text-white">Add category</h1>
<form action="{{route('categories.store')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="w-75 mx-auto">
@csrf
<div class="form-group">
<label for="formgroupexampleinput">Title</label>
<input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="formgroupexampleinput">Image</label>
<input type="file" name="file" required >
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="formgroupexampleinput">Description</label>
<input type="text" name="description" class="form-control" required >
</div>
<input type="submit" class="form-control btn-primary w-25" value="Submit">
</form>
<h1>Categoreis Data</h1>
<table class="table">
<tr>
<th>Title</th>
<th>Description</th>
<th>Edit</th>
<th>Delete</th>
</tr>
@foreach($categories as $cat)
<tr>
<td>{{$cat->title}}</td>
<td>{{$cat->description}}</td>
<td><a href="{{edit/{{$cat->id}}}}">Edit</a></td>
<td><a href="{{delete/{{$cat->id}}}}">Delete</a></td>
</tr>
@endforeach
</table>
</body>
</html>

@endsection
```

Comment: It probably should be `App\Models\Category`... Case is important in some environments, and if not, you should at least try to be consistent. All your other `use ...;` imports use `TitleCase`, so maybe they **all** should. Also, `Category::all()`, not `category::all()`.

Comment: hey, I have already tried this. thanks for the suggestion. any other possible solution?

Comment: For the next time, better to show the error to the community than say "error pops-up"

Comment: Do you have a file in `app\Models` directory called `Category.php`, with `namespace App\Models;`, called `class Category extends Model`? If the answer to that is no, then you'll need to fix that :) A screenshot of your directory, and the contents of that file (first few lines anyway) would help us debug this further.

Comment: Hey, thank you very much for the solution. Really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the model name because the server consists of file names that are case sensitive. In your case use `app\models\Category;`